# Does the --git argument in git-lfs-migrate tie the destination repo to that argument somehow?

Tags: git, git-lfs

The `--git` argument to `git-lfs-migrate` (and the `--lfs` argument) point to a remote server. Does that imply that the converted repository specified by `--destination` is somehow linked with this remote server?

As far as I can tell, no LFS objects are uploaded during the conversion, and the destination repository doesn't have the server from `--git` as a remote, so I'm not sure what the argument is even for. What's stopping me from running the conversion once with garbage as the `--git` argument, then adding a remote afterwards and pushing there?

I ask because I want to convert a repository to LFS then push to several git servers to test them out, and would like to avoid running the migrate step several times - if I can run it once and push to several remotes instead, that would save me some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question; the argument appears to do nothing at all. Two repositories I have created with different URLs passed to `--git` are binary identical.